# Unable to display HTML code generated by a PHP script in a new browser window using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have written a PHP script called generateemail.php that accepts input from a user and then combines their input with a template to compose a full HTML page ready to be sent out to customers.

The problem being that I would like the script to open a separate browser window displaying the content - I can get the code to pass through to the new window but it is displaying as code and not actually processing it as shown in the screenshot.

```js
<script>

function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace('&amp;', '&').replace('&lt;', '<').replace('&gt;', '>').replace('&quot;', '\"');
}

function printClick() {
  var w = window.open();
  var html = "<?php echo preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", htmlspecialchars($emailheader) ); ?>";
  var html2 = "<?php echo preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", htmlspecialchars($emailbody) ); ?>";
  
  
 
  // how do I write the html to the new window with JQuery?

    $(w.document.head).html(html).val();
 $(w.document.body).html(html2).val();
}

</script>
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQVyi.png

Comment: Remove val(), it is used for input fields and textarea values. Try it like this $(w.document.head).html(html); $(w.document.body).html(html2);

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have now tried that but it is the same as before - still bring the data through and not rendering it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by using Base64

```
<script>


var Base64 = {

    _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

    decode: function(input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        while (i < input.length) {

            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }

        }

        output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

        return output;

    },

    _utf8_decode: function(utftext) {
        var string = "";
        var i = 0;
        var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

        while (i < utftext.length) {

            c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

            if (c < 128) {
                string += String.fromCharCode(c);
                i++;
            }
            else if ((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                i += 2;
            }
            else {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
                c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 2);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                i += 3;
            }

        }

        return string;
    }

}


function printClick() {
  var w = window.open();
  var html = "<?php echo $emailheader; ?>";
  var html2 = "<?php echo $emailbody; ?>";


  var decodedString = Base64.decode(html);
  var decodedString2 = Base64.decode(html2);


$(w.document.head).html(decodedString);
$(w.document.body).html(decodedString2);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this http://jsfiddle.net/ty368zfr/

You can't use jQuery so use pure javascript

```
 w.document.head.innerHTML = html;
 w.document.body.innerHTML = html2;
```

Comment: I have tried that, the same thing happens again. I have tried:

alert(html) and also alert(htmlEntities(html)) and have found out that there are still HTML entities that are encoded. Here is a screenshot of both: http://imgur.com/HGxqej4

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the concatentation of your html strings. Try something like this:

```
var html = '<?php echo preg_replace( "/\\r|\\n/", "", htmlspecialchars($emailheader) ); ?>';
var html2 = '<?php echo preg_replace( "/\\r|\\n/", "", htmlspecialchars($emailbody) ); ?>';
```

You should also remove the `val()` function call. It isn't necessary to place your html code!

```
$(w.document.head).html(html);
$(w.document.body).html(html2);
```

Comment: Thank you but the issue is still present when trying this method

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are encoding html using htmlspecialcharacter.
there are a solution be removing it

```
<?php
$emailheader="<meta charset='utf-8' /><title>Sample header</title>";
$emailbody="<p>Some body</p>";
?>

    <script>
        var w = window.open();

      var html = "<?php echo preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", htmlspecialchars($emailheader) ); ?>";
      var html2 = "<?php echo preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", htmlspecialchars($emailbody) ); ?>";

     console.log(html);//Result :  &lt;meta charset='utf-8' /&gt;&lt;title&gt;Sample header&lt;/title&gt;

      var html = "<?php echo preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $emailheader ); ?>";
      var html2 = "<?php echo preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $emailbody ); ?>";

      console.log(html);//Result : <meta charset='utf-8' /><title>Sample header</title>

        w.document.head.innerHTML = html;
        w.document.body.innerHTML = html2;
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have tried it but receive the error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I think this is because the second set of html/html2 variables contains non-escaped double-quotes as shown in this screenshot - http://imgur.com/HH1TZmT